# Discovery Doc URL for Search Console API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-search-console, google-api-js-client

Trying to use the [Google JavaScript Client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) to query the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/how-tos/authorizing) and I'm not sure what to use for the discovery doc URL to use

```
{
  apiKey: '...',
  scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
  discoveryDocs: [
    '???',
  ]
  client_id: '...',
}
```

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Discovery Services API](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) is an API with a list of all the Google Discovery APIs.  Each API has an entry.  [Response](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis)

You are probably looking for the following:

> "discoveryDocs": "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/customsearch/v1/rest",

The Js client library is a bit different from the other libraries it reads directly from the discovery doc for the api you are trying to access rather then being prebuilt.  Thats why you need the link in question.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the helpful link from [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)
 (https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis), I found the discoveryAPI I was looking for:

`https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/webmasters/v3/rest`

Comment: The question is about **custom search** if you had wanted webmasters you should have asked for that and i would have given you that link.   In the future when asking questions please ensure that you are actuate.

Comment: Webmaster Tools has been publicly renamed to Search Console and in my question I explicitly linked to the appropriate API which is indeed named "Search Console".